# Do death triggers still happen if I am at 0 or less life after combat damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Here's the situation: I'm the defending player and being attacked for lethal damage.  I block with all my creatures but still would take enough damage to bring me to 0.  Among my blocking creatures are two [Zulaport Cutthroat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=402101)s.  After combat damage is assigned and I go to less than 0, would I still gain the life from my creatures dying via the Cutthroats?

Comment: I think [this other question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23941/will-i-die-if-i-lose-enough-life-to-kill-me-from-an-effect-that-also-heals-me) covers what you're asking.

Comment: @murgatroid99 All examples in the linked question deal and heal at the same time. This is different because Cutthraot does not use a damage-based trigger, but one that resolves separately.

Comment: And to expand on @steenbergh's point, the question itself is asking about effects which both deal damage and prevent it (or offset it) as part of a single resolution. So I don't think this is a duplicate. Some of the answers there do also address this question, but I don't think that matters.

Comment: @steenbergh That is not true. One of the examples is Armadillo Cloak, which is a triggered ability that causes life gain.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what happens:

1. Combat damage is assigned and dealt - no stack
2. Your life total is set to (less than) 0, creatures that were dealt lethal damage are moved to the graveyard. Cutthroat;s ability is placed on the stack X times, once for each creature that died.
3. Before Cutthroat's triggered ability can resolve however, you have already died because [coming to 0 life](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Life) or less is a [state-based effect](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/State-based_actions). Whatever's on the stack doesn't resolve anymore.